# Using random numbers with OnClickListener Android

Tags: java, android

The program I'm trying to developed has two buttons with random numbers on them  and allows the user to select the biggest. It should reset the numbers after each guess and keep score for the correct guesses but the problem I'm having is with the `OnClickListener` I have to make my two int values final to access them from the `OnClickListener` but this means the random values won't change. Is there anyway around this to make it work?

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    TextView textView1;
    int correctCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //retrive the Button and TetView objects
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);;

        Random randd = new Random();
         final int value = randd.nextInt(100)+1;
         final int value2 = randd.nextInt(100)+1;

        btn1.setText("" + value);
        btn2.setText("" + value2);
        textView1.setText("Correct = ");

        //register a listener for button clicks to be an anonymous
        //OnClickListener object with the onClick event handler
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(value > value2){
                    btn1.setText("" + value);
                    btn2.setText("" + value2);
                    correctCount++;
                    textView1.setText("Correct = " + correctCount);
                }


            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(value2 > value){
                    btn1.setText("" + value);
                    btn2.setText("" + value2);
                    correctCount++;
                    textView1.setText("Correct = " + correctCount);
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize value and value2 outside of onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function for example:

```
   public void resetButtonNumbers(){
    Random randd = new Random();
    value = randd.nextInt(100)+1;
    value2 = randd.nextInt(100)+1;

    btn1.setText("" + value);
    btn2.setText("" + value2);
}
```

And then just invoke this in each on click.

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(value2 > value){
            correctCount++;
            textView1.setText("Correct = " + correctCount);
        }
          resetButtonNumbers();

    }
});
```

Also, you need to make value variables as a class members:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int value;
private int value2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, I got this method to work with some tweaking :)

Comment: @S.Byrne Great, please accept/upvote my answer if it helped you :) I will appreciate that :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the variables as a **class scope**. Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private int value;
  private int value2;
}
```

Now you can access them from your `OnClickListener`. Please always make your variable more readable. So, instead naming the variable as `value`, you can use `mFirstRandom`. The previous variables can be change to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private int mFirstRandom;
  private int mSecondRandom;
}
```

Comment: @oksett: Why the downvoting? Could you please tell me the reason?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function for both buttons, this function will get the current value of each button and compare if it's bigger than the other. If yes it will add the score, if not it will do nothing. After clicking any of the buttons, the numbers on each button will reset. See `functionDoCount`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    TextView textView1;
    int correctCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //retrive the Button and TetView objects
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);;

        Random randd = new Random();
        int value = randd.nextInt(100)+1;
        int value2 = randd.nextInt(100)+1;

        btn1.setText("" + value);
        btn2.setText("" + value2);
        textView1.setText("Correct = ");

        //register a listener for button clicks to be an anonymous
        //OnClickListener object with the onClick event handler
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                functionDoCount(1);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                functionDoCount(2);
            }
        });

    }

    void functionDoCount(int buttonIndex) {
        int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(btn1.getText().toString());
        int currentValue2 = Integer.parseInt(btn2.getText().toString());

        if(buttonIndex == 1) { // if first button is clicked
            if(currentValue > currentValue2){
                correctCount++;
                textView1.setText("Correct = " + correctCount);
            }
        } else { // if the other button is clicked
            if(currentValue2 > currentValue){
                correctCount++;
                textView1.setText("Correct = " + correctCount);
            }
        }

        Random randd = new Random();
        int value = randd.nextInt(100)+1;
        int value2 = randd.nextInt(100)+1;
        btn1.setText("" + value);
        btn2.setText("" + value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what's with the down vote? I tested it in android studio my self and it works as intends to. It answers the question as well. It eliminates the 'final' it adds score when bigger number is correct, and it reset numbers after selection.

Comment: you can ask @oksett about the downvote. He/she is the one who downvoting your answer.